# cant include drupal_get_form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

i've drupal 6 module and i try to upgrade manual to drupal 7, i try to load another funtion that show form with drupal_get_form but nothing happend,

here's the code

```
function page_dashboard_penjualan() {
  global $user;

  $rid=db_query("select rid from users_roles where uid = '$user->uid'")->fetchAssoc();
  //$rid = db_select('users_roles','rid')
  //->fields('rid')
  //->condition('uid',$user->uid)
  //->execute()
  //->fetchAssoc();

  if($user->uid=="1" or $rid->rid=="32"){
        module_load_include('modules', 'display_ket', 'modules/product/display_ket/display_ket.module'); 
    $output = drupal_get_form('findlstappkr_dashboard');
        $output = tabel_dashboard_penjualan();

  } else {
    $output = "Maaf, Halaman ini hanya bisa diakses oleh bagian Penjualan";
  }
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting value of $output in the very next row after you are getting it. It's never used. Are you sure you are doing the right thing?

Comment: sure iam doing the right thing couse i know its code run perfectly in drupal 6 module

Comment: As I said, from the code you posted, value returned by drupal_get_form() is immediately overwritten by next row call.